# Adding Excel Sheet Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted some help in excel as i have low expertise in it, How do you add a formula on a excel sheet and 
secondly i want to add a formula on a column which do something like this

```
Text-> ABCD
```

Formula should add ' at the start of the text

```
Text->6/11
```

Formula should make it '6/11

When ever user types something in that column it should add ' at the start of the text

Comment: You might need vba scripts for that. If you want it to be done on another column, it can be done without scripts. you want in same column or  other column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCATENATE with the two cells.
Syntax is:
= CONCATENATE ( cell1, cell2, ... )

Comment: what if i wanted to write a formula on one exact cell only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this effect by formulas. In a cell there is a either a value or a formula.
If user types something in a cell with a formula, the formula is gone. You can define a second column B next to you input column A and put `=CONCATENATE("'", A1)` in B1 and copy this formula down the B column.

To manipulate the cell where the input took place you will need VBA.

Comment: can't we do it without vba ? i want that what ever you write in that cell it should place ' at the start of it.

Comment: I have to correct myself and admit to BOTS_306 (the other post). I tried it and it worked. At least for pure text. The 6/11 is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom number format for your cell (or range of cells) that would look like this:

"'"#;"'"-#;"'"0#;'@

This way positive integers, negative integers, zero values and text values within that range will all be displayed with a ' at the start of the text.

Comment: This doesn't quite work as Excel will interpret 6/11 as a sum and display '1 in any cell that has this custom formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the formula and values in 1 single cell can only be possible via VBA. If you do not want to use VBA, you will need 2 columns for sure. 1 to get the data entered and 2nd to write the formula to get the output. `Concatenate()` will do just fine for you.